# Steam doesn't run, no error

Tags: 13.04, steam

I'm trying to run Steam, this problem seems to have started when I updated Steam yesterday.

I get this output, but nothing after that. Steam does not start

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 13.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
$
```

Can anyone suggest a way that I can get more information about this or fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error this morning.

I just uninstalled it:

```
sudo apt-get remove steam*
```

Then I went in my home folder and removed the `.steam` folder, 
and then ran

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

then rebooted and opened steam.

Comment: Will I have to re-download all my games then?

Comment: no. I mean, i did have all my games the way they were.