# Steam not running on Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit

Tags: 13.04, 32-bit, steam

Steam just stopped to work. It worked fine until a couple of days ago, but now it won't launch. I've tried both to restart the computer and reinstall Steam, but it makes no difference. When I tried to launch it from the console I get only this:

```
marc@marc-UX21E:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 13.04 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
```

Any idea about what may it be?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I have tried to launch it after a computer restart and got some kind of error after trying to update Steam:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 13.04 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1378500910_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1378500910_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1378500910_client)
unlinked 0 orphaned pipes
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1378500910_client)
[0916/102432:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(958)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem (not sure about the 'after restart' part, though). Steam would start then exit without printing an error. I asked a question about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345619/steam-doesnt-run-no-error).

The solution which worked for me was

1. Remove Steam with this

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove steam*
   ```
2. Remove everything from the `~/.local/share/Steam` folder **except** `SteamApps`
3. Reinstall Steam with this

   ```
   sudo apt-get install steam-launcher
   ```

Credits to [Rat2000](https://askubuntu.com/users/79423/rat2000) for his [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/345620/176889)

Note: I had used the Steam `.deb` file from the official website and so had the Steam repo enabled

Comment: I am installing it right now, I hope it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Steam on ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.
I ended up doing a clean reinstall of ubuntu, since I was already considering it for a while.

What happens if you go on a terminal and type STEAM_RUNTIME=0 steam ? I read somewhere that this worked for some people.
If it tells you that libraries are missing, you might want to try typing sudo apt-get install ia32-libs and see how that goes.

If that doesn't work either, then you're in the same situation as me. For me, however, a clean install of ubuntu fixed it.

Comment: I have already tried the STEAM_RUNTIME=0 and got the same result, only saying that this was disabled by the user. I'll try to fix it in some other way, but if I can't I'll reinstall Ubuntu. Thank you very much!